# Como subdividir una lista en varias listas

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist

estoy intentando hacer un proceso que inserte en una tienda Online una serie de artículos devueltos en una consulta SQL y almacenados en una lista de artículos.
El proceso por lotes que debo ejecutar para insertar estos artículos en la tienda Online, no admite más de 100 artículos simultáneos, por lo que debo subdividir la lista de productos en varias listas de 100 o menos productos.
Mi idea era crear listas con un rango de artículos de la lista principal y añadir las listas en un `ArrayList`, pero no sé cómo hacer un `ArrayList.add()` de una lista creada dinámicamente con el contenido de un `GetRange()` de la lista principal.
No sé si la manera de enfocarlo es la correcta y como debo proseguir.
Gracias.

**EDIT**

```
    List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
    ArrayList multilist = new ArrayList();
    if (productes.Count > 100)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int max = productes.Count();
        while (max > 100)
        {
            multilist.Add(new List<Product>());
            multilist[i] = productes.GetRange(i, 100);
            max -= 100;
            i++;
        }
        if (max > 0)
        {
            multilist.Add(new List<Product>());
            multilist[i] = productes.GetRange(i, max);
        }
    }
```

Esto es lo más que he conseguido, pero no funciona demasiado bien y no me parece la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Comment: hola miguel y cual es el código que has intentado desarrollar? recuerda colocar codigo para ver error o posible soluciones entre la comunidad te ayude

Comment: Perdón, edito mi pregunta añadiendo el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta algo confuso el código pero entiendo que quieres subdividir listas
para ello tienes que ir contando cada 100 item de tu lista Productes y agregandola a una lista nueva pero seria como hacer varias listas nuevas por cada 100 y si hubiera 1 millón de items?

Encontré algo en este [hilo de stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/4668184)

```
 public static IList<IList<T>> Split<T>(IList<T> source)
{
    return  source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Pero solo cada 3 como puedes ver en la división del x.index /3; así que debes parametrizar ese número el método:

```
public static IList<IList<T>> Split<T>(IList<T> source, int **numArt**)
    {
        return  source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / **numArt**)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
```

Otra buena solución que encontré fue [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463800/4668184) que se acerca más a lo que estas buscando:

```
public static List<List<Product>> SplitList(List<Product> locations, int nSize=30)  
{        
    var list = new List<List<Product>>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i += nSize) 
    { 
        list.Add(locations.GetRange(i, Math.Min(nSize, locations.Count - i))); 
    } 

    return list; 
}
```